intent:// URI not invoking component
I was trying to craft a correct "intent://" URI for following purpose:

Component: com.myapp/.ui.SignIn
Extra String: link
scheme: myapp://

To simply put, I want to translate following command to intent:// uri if thats possible.
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myapp://" -n com.myapp/.ui.SignIn --es "link" "<login_link>"
As per my case, I want solution with intent:// URI only not via standard deeplink implementation. Thanks for your help.
Tried out following link on Android Chrome browser after some online articles, however I am unable to invoke components using "component=". Is there a particular requirement, note that SignIn Activity is exported and it has intent filters (with category android.intent.category.BROWSABLE, do I require DEFAULT too?) Also, if I specify "package=" it redirects me to google playstore even if app is installed:
<a href="intent:#Intent;scheme=myapp;component=com.myapp/.ui.SignIn;S.link=https://<login_link>;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end >
